# Cardview size on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

So what I wanna do is to have a recycler view with images inside each card.

How can I know the width of each card so I can pass the images to the adapter with the exact size and take the entire space of the card? (I want the images to have all the same size.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:id="@+id/phone_card_imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is the code I have on the cardview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `layout_width` and `layout_height` to fixed size in dp for your `ImageView`, that will do the trick.
Note that you can also fix only the height, and the width will be the one of the screen.

Comment: That did not solved the problem, but i did it to the card size and now I know exactly what kind of image I need

Comment: Oh, I did not see your card has match_parent. Of layout for list item should always wrap its content in height, or at least fix the size, so you had a problem here that's true